# Given distinct positive integers $a, b, c$ and $2^a\cdot2^b\cdot2^c =64$, what is $2^a+2^b+2^c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

> Suppose that $a,b$ and $c$ are distinct positive integers and $2^a\cdot2^b\cdot2^c =64$. Find $2^a+2^b+2^c$.

This is so far my work: I got $2^a\cdot2^b\cdot2^c=2^6$ then $abc=6$ is this so far in the right track?

Comment: no. a+b+c=6. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Not $abc=6$, but $a+b+c=6$. Exponents *add* when base is constant. Oddly enough, the solution in distinct positive integers to $abc=6$ is the same as the solution to the (correct) $a+b+c=6$.

Comment: @Little Jon Following up on the above comments: since they are all different (between each other) you can assume, [without loss of generality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that $a<b<c$. Now see what happens if $a=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$2^a \cdot 2^b\cdot 2^c = 2^{a + b + c} = 2^6\;\;\iff\;\; a + b + c = 6$$

(Recall that $2^x\cdot 2^y = 2^{x+y}.$)

The only possible combinations of *distinct* $a, b, c$ which sum to $6$ is $\;(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3),\;$ or any permutation thereof.*
That is, $$a \neq b \neq c \implies 2^a + 2^b + 2^c = 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 = 2 + 4 + 8 = 14.$$

*(Because of symmetry, we do not need to consider $a = 2, b = 1, c = 3,$ etc. All we need to know is if a, b, c are distinct, then we need one of a, b, c to be $1$, one to be $2$, and one to be $3$.)

Comment: Thanks, @GitGud - corrected.

Comment: Many many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Little Jon!

Comment: Assistance would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Alrighty then :)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice very nice. :-)

Comment: Thanks, Babak! And how are you doing?

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$2^a\cdot2^b\cdot2^c=2^{a+b+c}$ and $64=2^6$.

You know that $2^a\cdot2^b\cdot2^c=64$, then you have that $2^{a+b+c}=2^6$, and from this you conclude that $a+b+c=6$.

Solution $(a,b,c)= (1,2,3)$, therefore $2^a+2^b+2^c= 2^1+2^2+2^3=2+4+8=14$.

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{a}\cdot2^{b}\cdot2^{c}=2^{a+b+c}$$
$$a+b+c=6$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's the $log$ solution,

$log 2^{a+b+c}=log 64$

$(a+b+c).(0.3010)=6.(0.3010)$

$a+b+c=6$

$a \neq b \neq c \implies log 2^a\neq log 2^b \neq log 2^c$

$log 2^{a+b+c}=log2^a+log2^b+log2^c=6.log2$

$a,b,c$ are distinct, therefore $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3),(3,2,1),(1,3,2),(2,3,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,2)$

Therefore, $2^a+2^b+2^c= 2+ 4+ 8 = 14$